Does this sentence need "it" to make sense?

I woke up with a stiff neck. It hurts to move [it]"

Should I add "it" in the sentence above?

It depends on what you mean.
"It hurts to move" means that any movement causes pain.
Adding "it" makes it refer specifically to moving your neck -- the antecedent of "it" is your neck that's stiff. So it only hurts when you move your neck, not when you move other parts of your body.

The question is whether you could say, "My neck hurts to move", isn't it? In this case, "it" in the original question could be taken to refer to "stiff neck" in the preceding sentence.

You can't say that. You could say "My neck hurts when I move it."

@MariosAthanasiou Yes, I'm a native English speaker. But I'm not a linguist or language expert, so I don't know many of the technical terms for language constructions. I'm not sure why your answer was downvoted, but so were other answers.
